# JQuery DatePicker default to the next available date

Tags: jquery-ui

My calendar only allows Tuesdays and Thursdays to be available for selection.
I want the default date in the input field to be the next available date. For example if I open the page on a Wednesday, I would like Thursday's date to be in the input field by defautl.
Right now I have "Today's date". How do I change my code to select the next available date?

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "/b/i/Calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 0,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date)
    { return [(date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 4), ""]; } //Tuesdays and Thursdays
});
if($("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
    //select today's date
    var myDate = new Date();
            var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var todayDate = month + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
            $("#datepicker").val(todayDate);
}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to this piece of code to get next tuesday/thursday.
There must a smarter way but it works :o)

Here's the code:

```
var $datePicker = $("#datepicker");

if ($datePicker.datepicker("getDate") === null) {

    var today = new Date(),
        todayDay = today.getDay(),
        day = ((todayDay >= 2 && todayDay < 4 )
                   ? 4
                   : (todayDay >= 4 && todayDay <= 6)
                        ? 9
                        : 2) - todayDay,
        nextDay = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + day));

    $datePicker.val((nextDay.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + nextDay.getDate() + '/' + nextDay.getFullYear());

}
```

I've made [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/WptVk/) so you see it in action.